# Custom dynamic routes using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

There is little unconventional routes requirement for a project i am working on. The route has following structure `/<--name-->-abc-xyz-<--id-->` where name and id are dynamic. Now i want to match this route using react router. So i did the following

`<Route path='/:name-abc-xyz-:id' component={View} />`

This fails for the cases where name name is of this form def-abc-xyz-*.

How to fix this such that i get value of name and id in View component directly.

I have a workaround where i do 
`<Route path='/:dynamicId' component={View} />`

and now i parse dynamicId and take out name and id from it in my View compoenent. Is there a way to achieve the following without parsing ?

Answer (score 2):

## Standard routing

The standard way how this is managed in V4 is to provide a route in config as:

```
/:name/abc-xyz/:id
```

If you are not constrained by another parser to use the above dashed-schema this solution will fit your needs.

Ref: https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config#route-configuration-shape

if you have conflict with static routes place the dynamic route last in route scaffolding

Ref: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-ambiguous-matches/

## Custom route formats

Additionaly, notice

> React Router uses path-to-regexp for its route matching.

This means that if you provide a route in this format:

```
/:name(\w+-)?abc-xyz(\w+-)?:id
```

This will work too while comparing (IE)

```
def-abc-xyz-12
```

## Screenshot from [route tester](https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/def-abc-xyz-12)

[image]
Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5536#issuecomment-330548834

Route tester: https://pshrmn.github.io/route-tester/#/def-abc-xyz-12